# Geocoding API in local installations

Tags: android, openstreetmap, graphhopper

I have installed graphhopper successfully on my local server instance and it works perfectly as for the routing api.
I wonder if the geocoding API is excluded from the local installation or has to be enabled somehow, because it seems to be not reachable under hostname:port/geocode or hostname:port/api/1/geocode , as documented in your docs...

Answer (score 0):

In the open source version of GraphHopper the geocoding part is not included and must be handled by an external project, see https://discuss.graphhopper.com/t/geocoding-in-open-source-edition/3667 and https://discuss.graphhopper.com/t/how-does-the-geocoding-service-in-graphhopper-work/3247/2. The commercial version of GraphHopper has a geocoder included.

For the open source version you have to install a separate geocoder such as Photon or Nominatim.

Comment: thanks.. I installed Photon and it's working fine @scai

Comment: Great! In this case please accept my answer :)